# how to solve $ T(n) = T (2n/3) + 1$ using master theorem?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I solved the above recurrence using master theorem and applied case $2$ to solve it.

However in the final answer I have $T(n) = \Theta(\log^{(k+1)} n)$ . what should happen to $k+1$? because the final answer is $T(n) = \Theta(\log n)$

If someone has a different approach, please do share.

Comment: What is $k$ in $\log^{(k+1)}n$?

Comment: @math1000, I came across it as k>=0, I put it as =0 but didnt give the same answer as I hoped it would

Comment: That doesn't answer the question...what does $k$ have to do with $n$?

Comment: @math1000 http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Master-theorem.pdf if you see page 3 , it talks about k what I told you and nothing more, I am also learning it from the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. There is no mention of $k$ in the expression $T(n)= T(2n/3) + 1$, so that reference is necessary to understand what you were talking about.

Comment: What goes wrong when you set $k=0$? It seems that setting $k=0$ is exactly what works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we have
$$T(n) = aT\left(\frac nb\right) + n^c $$
where $a=1$, $b=\frac32$, and $c=0$. 
Then $$\log_b a = \log_{\frac32} 1 = 0 = c,$$
so $$ T(n)\in\Theta(\log n).$$
In particular, using your reference, $k=0$ works, as $n^0\log^0 n = 1$ and
$$1\in\Theta(n^0\log^0n). $$

Comment: I should add that I was particular in asking what $k$ is because the "master theorem" tends to have different notation depending on the author.

Comment: A small typo: $b=3/2$ instead of $2/3$, as [o515](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/382722/o515) pointed out.

Comment: which case is applied here?  I think it's case 2, the "theta" one but unsure.

Comment: Perhaps it is interesting to see how $$b = 3/2$$ is found.
The objective is to write the numbers in this form: $$T(n) = aT\left(\frac nb\right) + n^c $$
as you can see we do not have this yet. Since we have $$T(n) = 2T(2n/3)$$ So in order to go from 2n/3 to n/.. , we do (2n/2)/(3/2), hence now we get $$T(n) = 2T(n/(3/2))$$

Answer (score 1):

Here, $b=\frac32$, not $\frac23$. At first glance, the master theorem shows the inverse of $b$.

Comment: This does not answer the question directly, and is more suitable for a comment.